# iOS UITesting Tap on uiview or PSTCollectionViewCell

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, xcode-ui-testing, pstcollectionview

I have used PSTCollectionView for collection view. As a result, when I record for UITesting and tap on that cell, it can't generate properly.

```
XCUIApplication *app = [[XCUIApplication alloc] init];
[app tap];
```

How shall I do to simulate for that case? My view hierarchy is as shown below.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to interact with a `UILabel`s directly. To tap on the "Shopping" cell try the following.

```
XCUIApplication *app = [[XCUIApplication alloc] init];
[app.staticTexts[@"Shopping"] tap];
```